# Where and how to instantiate inputmaps and actionmaps

Tags: java, key-bindings

I am making a classic "move image around on the screen" program. Instead of a Keylistener, I am trying to get keybindings to work but so far without success.

My objects are in a linkedlist

```
public LinkedList<GameObject> object = new LinkedList<GameObject>();
```

and added to this list via

```
public void addObject(GameObject object){
    this.object.add(object);
}
```

My KeyBinding class is as follows

```
public class KeyBindings extends JPanel{

private static final String accelerate = "accelerate";

public KeyBindings(){
    System.out.println("test");
    registerKeyBinding(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, false), "UP-press", new ShuttleMove(accelerate));
}

public void registerKeyBinding(KeyStroke keyStroke, String name, Action action) {
    InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    ActionMap am = getActionMap();

    im.put(keyStroke, name);
    am.put(name, action);
}

class ShuttleMove extends AbstractAction {

    public ShuttleMove(String movement) {

            if (movement.equals("accelerate")){
                //this.setVelocityForward(this.getVelocityForward() + 0.1);
                System.out.println("accelerate");
            }
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }
}
```

}

My Player class, which extends the GameObject class looks (slightly condensed) as:

```
public class Player extends GameObject {

Handler handler;

public Player(int x, int y, ID id, int width, int height, int rotation,double totalRotation, Handler handler, double velocityForward, double velocityRotate){
    super(x, y, id, width, height, rotation, totalRotation);
    this.handler = handler;

}

public void tick(){ 
    x += this.getVelocityForward();
    y += this.getVelocityForward();
}
public void render(Graphics2D g2d){

    try {
        player = ImageIO.read(new File("src/Game/images/shuttle3.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    AffineTransform old = g2d.getTransform();
    AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x,y);     

    g2d.drawImage(player, at,null);
    g2d.setTransform(old);
}
}
```

I am not sure how to "activate" the keybinding though. Should it be in the main loop? Should it be in the player.tick method which is called to update the player image and subsequently draw it?

Also, how is the inputmap and actionmap associated with the player object? I tried doing something like this, which did not work:

```
public void registerKeyBinding(KeyStroke keyStroke, String name, Action action) {
    for (int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++){
        GameObject player = handler.object.get(i);
        //find player
        if (player.getID() == ID.Player){
            InputMap im = player.getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap am = player.getActionMap();

            im.put(keyStroke, name);
            am.put(name, action);
        }
    }
}
```

I think some how my player should be cast to a JComponent but I am not sure how this is done (as Eclipse tells me it is not compatible with my GameObject class). Can anyone guide me in the right direction? Let me know if I accidently left out some crucial information (which I am quite sure I did)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to "activate" the keybinding, it's already activated once you populate the `ActionMap`. What you *do* need to do is implement the actionPerfomed method of the `Action` object. The `Action` object is essentially an action *handler*. It should not do anything once it's created, it should only do things once the action is actually performed.

Comment: Also, as a followup, I think you are misinterpreting the meaning of _register_ here. "Registering" a key handler means adding the functionality of listening for the keypress, **not** registering the click itself. Therefore, you should move your key functionality to the actionPerformed method and not do any logic in the functionality that registers the handler - as what it essentialy does is just say "start listening to the respective keypress".

Comment: You already did, by calling getActionMap on the Player object. When the event gets fired, the ActionEvent should contain the player as the source - you just have to cast it to Player.

Comment: Sorry for deleting my comment. Was editing. I wanted to try something like    class ShuttleMove extends AbstractAction {

  public ShuttleMove(Object player) {
   this.player = player;
  }
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   this.setVelocityForward(this.getVelocityForward() + 0.1);
  }
 } I may miss something conceptually though, as I am unsure how to cast it to the player. Anyways, I will read up on it asap. Thank you for the response.

Comment: Not `this`. `e.getSource()`. `this` in the context is the **handler**. You want the object that evoked the keypress event. You need something like `Player p = (Player) e.getSource(); p.setVelocityForward(p.getVelocityForward() + 0.1);`

Comment: I think this is what confuses me. How can I get the object (in this case an object with the player.id == player from a linked list) to evoke the keypress event? I can add Player p = (Player) e.getSource(); to the action performed but the registerKeyBinding method is never called. I've tried to loop through my linked list and when I find my object with the player.id == player, I set InputMap am = player.getInputMap. However, the method getInputMap is undefined for the type GameObject (which describes the objects in the linked list). Casting to JComponent does not work. Any ideas?